# What are the best practices to create Azure pipeline dashboard. What is better to use workbook(KQL) or logs>query(KQL) to create dashboard?

Tags: excel, azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-dashboard

What are the best practices to create Azure pipeline dashboard.
what is better to use workbook(KQL) or logs>query(KQL) to create dashboard?

Comment: could you please clarify what you mean by logs>query(KQL)? In workbooks you can use KQL to query logs as well so not sure what you are the two different options you are considering.

Comment: Hi Ravit.. I am new to log analytics, and exploring it. I saw we have two options to write KQL, in workbook and in logs also, what is best to use... 
Direct query(in logs) and pin to dashboard or writing query in the workbook and pin to dashboard?

Comment: Hi Neha, if the answer below is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, both them are providing almost the same feature when creating a dashboard.

As far as I can remember, just in case you need to create a dashboard which needs a [cross query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cross-workspace-query)(like query from 2 different `azure log analytics`), `in workbooks` you don't need to write query code for cross query since you can select more than 1 resources via UI, but `in logs` you need to write query code by using keyword like [workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cross-workspace-query#querying-across-log-analytics-workspaces-and-from-application-insights) for cross query.

So, in normal cases, you can just use the logs to create dashboard.